# Call local JavaScript function from dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, html, scope

I have a JavaScript file that gets included on customers' websites to perform visitor surveys. All of the code is in an anonymous function and this is causing issues now that I need to dynamically generate HTML for the surveys.

Basically, the HTML for the survey gets generated using JavaScript (as a div) and added to the DOM. Part of that HTML has hyperlinks to other functions (close, submit, etc), but it can't see any of the functions I have inside my anonymous function wrapper. I don't want to expose all of my methods just for this one piece. Is there any way I can get the dynamic HTML to see my functions? Also, I can't use jQuery.

```
(function () {
...
function displaySurvey(x) {
        /// <summary>Server callback to display a survey to the user.</summary>
// content is a DIV I added to the DOM using createElement and appendChild
 content.innerHTML += "<div><span onclick='go()' style='cursor:pointer'>Submit</span>&nbsp;<span onclick='closeSurvey()' style='cursor:pointer'>Close</span></div>";

}

function closeSurvey()
{

}
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create your `elements`, set the `onclick`, and append to `content`, using JavaScript so that the elements have a handle to your private functions (do to the nature of closures).

I think this is approximately what you are trying to do ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4bNb/)):

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var content = document.getElementById( "div1" );

(function() {
    function appendSpan() {
        var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
        newSpan.onclick = privateFunction;
        newSpan.innerHTML = "click on me!";
        content.appendChild(newSpan);
    }

    function privateFunction() {
        alert("i am private");
    }
    appendSpan();
}())
```

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work. I moved my close above the append and where the append gets called from but it doesn't see it. Does it matter that I am setting the innerhtml after appending?

Comment: Maybe i missed what you were saying about the elements. I guess I need to create the span manually. I will try that and get back,

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites: The most important line is `newSpan.onclick = privateFunction;`.  You need to set the click handler that way as opposed to in an HTML string like you are currently doing.

Comment: You're a freaking genius man. I learn something new every day.

Comment: One small note on this approach... the onclick events break if I try to append anything else using innerhtml.. so i have to append each element manually after this point although i guess I could create another div and assign it's inner html:

        var closeBtn = document.createElement("span");
        closeBtn.onclick = closeSurvey;
        closeBtn.innerHTML = "Close";
        
        content.appendChild(closeBtn);
        content.innerHTML += "</div>"; // problem here

Comment: This would make it tricky though if all I'm trying to append is a closing tag. not sure how I could accomplish that without appending as I show in my comment above.

Comment: @KingOfHypocrites: Why not create the outer `div` tag using `document.createElement` too, so that you don't have a half constructed element hanging out?

Comment: It would take pages of code to add every div and span one by one and then assign properties one by one. I'm thinking there must be a better way but maybe not. I have to keep my script as small as possible because it goes on other people's websites. I ended up putting the full code inside the onclick in the case where the div was in the middle and the one at the end I was able to do the way you showed me.

Comment: Found a way to combine the best of both worlds. Added an answer with tips for others in case you are curious. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Not to take away from the original answer which is correct, but some tips for anyone trying to do this:

I've found the secret is just to create an outer div (using createElement) that is empty and then set it's innerhtml to get things started. This prevents you from having to set all of the styles one by one. If you have a div with a ton of inner divs and styles, this will save you a lot of time and code. Then you will need to append your clickable items by creating the elements manually (via createElement and assigning onclick to the created elements as shown in accepted answer).

Note that you won't be able to find an element by id until you've added the greatest ancestor of where it's attached to the document, so you will have to make sure you add all of your nodes in the right order. Typically you will add your outer divs to the document, then find the element where you want to attach your buttons, then append them.

The other thing is you can't use += innerhtml on anything containing (a parent of) a clickable item (or it will break the onclick functionality of your inner clickable items). Therefore, you just have to make sure you have the proper inner divs you need to set any dynamic html. If you need to extend at the end of the html, add another div via createElement and set it's innerhtml appropriately to continue the process as needed.